# Trying to get user location using SwiftUI in the content view but showing nil

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-location, locationmanager, userlocation

I’m a beginner, trying to get the latitude and longitude from LocationManager and show it in the ContentView using SwiftUI but result showing nil. But the console prints the data from LocationManager class. Not showing the latitude and longitude from the content view. Can anyone help?
(Xcode 11)

This is the LocationManager class

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
private let manager: CLLocationManager
var willChange = PassthroughSubject<LocationManager, Never>()

var getLat: String = ""
var getLon: String = ""

var lastKnownLocation: CLLocation? {
    willSet {
        willChange.send(self)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .denied {
        print("denied")
    }
    else{
        print("athorized")
        manager.requestLocation()
    }
}

func start() {
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

init(manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()) {
    self.manager = manager
    super.init()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func startUpdating() {
    self.manager.delegate = self
    self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //print(locations)
    lastKnownLocation = locations.last
    
    getLat = "\(locations.last!.coordinate.latitude)"
    getLon = "\(locations.last!.coordinate.longitude)"
    
    showLocation()
}

func showLocation() {
    print("from showLocation")
    print("Latitude: \(getLat)")
    print("Longitude: \(getLon)")
}
```

}

[This is the console that shows the latitude and longitude from LocationManager class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qQh4.png)

This is the Content View

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var managerDelegate = LocationManager()
    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()
    @ObservedObject var location = LocationManager()

    var lat: String {
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0)"
    }

    var lon: String {
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)"
    }

    init() {
        self.manager.delegate = self.managerDelegate
        do {
            try self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World")
            Text("Latitude: \(lat)")
            Text("Longitude: \(lon)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[This is output of ContentView in the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aod5s.png)

Comment: Why not simply have an `@Published` location in your location manager?

Comment: Tried, didn’t work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found myself the time to *read* your code and I have a solution for you.

First, you'll want to set the delegate to the variable that you are observing, inside `ContentView.init()`:

```
self.manager.delegate = self.location
```

Immediately after, you'll want to call the `startUpdating()` function that you defined in `LocationManager`:

```
self.location.startUpdating()
```

Finally, you may want to remove your `will-change` implementation and opt for the more simple:

```
@Published var lastKnownLocation: CLLocation?
```

The published wrapper will automatically trigger object changes for you.

---

### Refactor

Now if you like, you can also reduce your init statement down to one line:

```
init() {
    self.location.startUpdating()
}
```

Which means you can freely remove a couple properties:

```
`@State var managerDelegate = LocationManager()`

`@State var manager = CLLocationManager()`
```

---

**TLDR;**
Here is a shortened version of the code:

**The content view**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var location = LocationManager()

    var lat: String {
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0)"
    }

    var lon: String {
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)"
    }

    init() {
        self.location.startUpdating()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Location breakdown")
            Text("Latitude: \(lat)")
            Text("Longitude: \(lon)")
        }
        .padding()
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}
```

**The Location Manager**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var lastKnownLocation: CLLocation?
    
    func startUpdating() {
        self.manager.delegate = self
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        lastKnownLocation = locations.last
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @David I updated my answer, hopefully it'll be helpful.